# Hom-functor (Bifunctor)

Tags: category-theory, self-learning

I'm having trouble seeing how just by having the (co- and contravariant) functors

- $Hom(a,-)\rightarrow Set$
- $Hom(-,b)\rightarrow Set$

I can define the bifunctor $F:C\times C\rightarrow Set$.

References:

- Page 38 of Maclane's CWM
- http://drexel28.wordpress.com/2011/12/31/product-of-categories-pt-ii/

The issue is that I cannot prove the bifunctor's axiom $F(f,g)\circ (h,i) = F(f,h)\circ F(g,i)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mapping $(X, Y) \mapsto Hom(X,Y)$ is a functor $C^{op} \times C \to Set$, (where $X, Y$ are objects of $C$) not $C \times C \to Set$.  This is how you get functoriality (what you called the bifunctor axiom).  To be more precise, if $f, g, h, i$ are morphisms in $C$, such that both $gi$ and $hf$ exist, and $f^*$, $h^*$ are the reversed morphisms in $C^{op}$, we get:

$$
  F( (f^*,g) \circ (h^*, i)) = F ( f^*h^*, gi ) = F( (hf)^*, gi) = gi\circ - \circ hf,
$$

which is postcomposition by $gi$ and precomposition by $hf$.  This mapping
acts on $\phi \in Hom(X, Y)$ by $\phi \mapsto gi\phi hf$.

On the other hand,

$$
  F(f^*, g) \circ F(h^*, i) = ( g \circ - \circ f ) \circ (i \circ - \circ h)
$$

These mappings act on $\phi \in Hom(X, Y)$ by:
$$
  ( g \circ - \circ f )\Big[(i \circ - \circ h)(\phi)\Big]
  = ( g \circ - \circ f )[i\phi h]
  = gi \phi hf.
$$

Thus,
$$
F( (f^*,g) \circ (h^*, i)) = F( (f^*,g) \circ (h^*, i)).
$$

Hope this helps!